# Android step counter sensor stops counting up

Tags: android, service, counter

I am building a tracking app that requires regular updates from the step counter. I have been working on this for a couple of months and have not faced any problems with the step counter so far. Now from one day to the next, the step counter is counting up to a certain number, then stops increasing the step number.

I am initializing the sensor from a foreground service like this:

```
float steps = 0;
mStepSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
mStepSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    System.out.println("TrackingService/onSensorChanged", "Steps: " + sensorEvent.values[0]);
    mSteps = sensorEvent.values[0];
}
```

After a reboot, the steps count up properly. Some time after a couple of thousand steps, the sensor just stops to emit any events. I haven't had that problem with exactly the same code in the past, but wanted to hear: Has anyone experienced a similar issue and can recommend a solution?

Comment: What android version are you running?

Comment: I'm running 6.0.1.

Comment: I dunno if this will help..have you tried changing from Delay Normal to delay fastest.. SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, it unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: I had it working but it was not that accurate in my phone, so I had to  implement the method from scratch.

Comment: A Nougat update seems to have solved it for me, so I think it was just a device-specific bug.